# provide header to pip install command

Tags: pip, artifactory, pypi

I have a local Artifactory repository and I wish to provide the URL to my users for them to be able to install the wheel. They are themselves not part of the Artifשבtory so I was thinking of using API KEY. According to the documentation -

```
our API key can be used to authenticate you when using the REST API.
To use the API key, add the following header to all REST API calls: 'X-JFrog-Art-Api: <YOUR_API_KEY>'
```

I have my command as such `pip install https://artifactory.myorg.com:443/artifactory/local-pypi-mywork-01/mypackage-0.1-py3-none-any.whl`

Is there a way to provide the API key as header to this URL request?

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you've asked, but maybe providing a solution:

```
pip install https://<username>:<api-key>@artifactory.myorg.com:443/artifactory/local-pypi-mywork-01/mypackage-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

However, it is more recommended to use access tokens. Access tokens are expirable and more limited in general.
You can create easily [access tokens with the JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-CreatingAccessTokens):

```
jfrog rt access-token-create froggy-user
```

And then:

```
pip install https://froggy-user:<token>@artifactory.myorg.com:443/artifactory/local-pypi-mywork-01/mypackage-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```